# How do I adapt the width of this box element?

Tags: css

I use lots of boxes to display information, and their current style is this:

```
.box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background: #ffffff;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen,
    Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Fira Sans", "Droid Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  color: #616161;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}
```

This stretches the box to the entire viewport, which is fine as it generally contains a long sentence. But now I am using this content:

```
<div class="box functions"><span class="material-icons green">emoji_people</span><span>Remember including:
<li>Your name.</li>
<li>Your nationality.</li>
<li>Your place of residence.</li>
<li>Your profession.</li>
<li>Your phone number.</li>
<li>Your email.</li>
</span></div>
```

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background: #ffffff;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Fira Sans", "Droid Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  color: #616161;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box functions"><span class="material-icons green">emoji_people</span><span>Remember including:
<li>Your name.</li>
<li>Your nationality.</li>
<li>Your place of residence.</li>
<li>Your profession.</li>
<li>Your phone number.</li>
<li>Your email.</li>
</span></div>
```

The result is lots of white space:
[image]

I understand I need to modify the width, doing something like `width: 50%`, but is there a way to adapt the width of the box to the content of the element? I've been looking into `flex-basis`, but I'm a beginner, and I'm finding the resources hard to understand.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid.  It is invalid to have `<li>` as a child of `<span>`

Comment: Unfortunately, inside WordPress there's an issue with <p> tags and the only workaround I found is using <span> instead.

Comment: List elements may only have [Flow Content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#flow_content) as children. Also what is your intended outcome? For the box to occupy the space in which the content creates and not stretch all the way to the other side of page?

Comment: @TannerDolby Exactly, I want that if the content inside the box is narrow, the box also stretches, but if it's wider, it becomes wider too. And having the box centred too, which I assume is achieved with `align-items: center`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you don't want the `.box` flex container to occupy 100% of the available width like its currently doing. One way to ensure the width of `.box` adapts to the content of the element is using [`width: fit-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/fit-content).

> *Note: `fit-content` isn't supported in Internet Explorer, so using the method below which doesn't use fit-content would ensure better support.*

To make sure the content is centered vertically and horizontally on the page. You could make the `body` (or another parent container) a flexbox and specify `min-height: 100vh` so the content fills at minimum 100% of the viewport height along with `align-items: center` to vertically align the child `.box` container along the cross-axis in the center of the page. To ensure that `.box` is centered horizontally along the main-axis, you can use `justify-content: center` or `margin: 0 auto` to take advantage of auto margins.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background: #ffffff;
  /* width: fit-content; Not needed with body (or parent) being flex container */
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Fira Sans", "Droid Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  color: #616161;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<div class="box functions"><span class="material-icons green">emoji_people</span><span>Remember including:
<ul>
<li>Your name.</li>
<li>Your nationality.</li>
<li>Your place of residence.</li>
<li>Your profession.</li>
<li>Your phone number.</li>
<li>Your email.</li>
</ul>
</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly! Thank you so much. Now the challenge is that is not centered. Shouldn't `align-items: center` work?

Adding `justify-content: center` doesn't work either: https://i.imgur.com/92dEcOB.png

Comment: Your welcome! The flex container just needs a parent container with an explicit height (or its own explicit height so `align-items` has more "room" to align along the cross-axis) or with the parent container scenario so .box can align vertically along the cross-axis with align-items: center like you've stated. Remember align-items in the .box are applying to the flex children in .box not the position of the flex container itself. Have a look at my updated answer.

Comment: @AlejandroGoffa Does this better answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

I would use a grid to align things.  Here I added some wrappers so I could manipulate each of the containers and added background colors for clarity.
Note how I was able to move the "Rembmer" to the second column, set the first to a fixed width of 80px, things like that.

```css
.my-container {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Fira Sans", "Droid Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  color: #616161;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #000000;
  width: fit-content;
}

.box {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 80px 1rem 1fr auto;
  grid-template-rows: 2rem 1rem 1rem);
  background-color: #ffddff;
}

.material-icons {
  align-self: center;
  background-color: #EEEEFF;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
  grid-column: 1 / 1;
}

.remember-header {
  align-self: center;
  justify-content: center;
  grid-column: 2 / span 2;
  grid-row: 1 / 1;
  background-color: #FFEEEE;
}

.group-items {
  align-self: center;
  grid-column: 3 / 4;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
  background-color: #EEFFEE;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-container">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="material-icons green">emoji_people</div>
    <div class='remember-header'>Remember including:</div>
    <ul class="group-items">
      <li>Your name.</li>
      <li>Your nationality.</li>
      <li>Your place of residence.</li>
      <li>Your profession.</li>
      <li>Your phone number.</li>
      <li>Your email.</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, Mark but this doesn't seem to solve the issue of the box having tons of empty space to the right. Should I apply `width: fit-content` too?

Comment: @AlejandroGoffa  Yes, I adjusted some (review the edit) and added that to the box and adjusted columns to reduce it - it can be cleaner but partially is to show some examples of the flexibility which is slightly higher than some other method.  Note where the emoji text exceeds its box but that could be clipped as well

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the display style of `.box` to `display: inline-block` so that it shrinks to content size. You also need to wrap its contents and the icon in flex containers to keep the original alignment (centered icon at the left of the contents). If you do not want it to look too compressed, you need to add some padding (here I put 30px, but you can change it to any value you like).

```css
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  align-items: center;
  background: #ffffff;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Fira Sans", "Droid Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  color: #616161;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  padding: 30px;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.icon-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="box functions">
  <div class="flex-container"><div class="icon-container"><span class="material-icons green">emoji_people</span></div><span>Remember including:
<li>Your name.</li>
<li>Your nationality.</li>
<li>Your place of residence.</li>
<li>Your profession.</li>
<li>Your phone number.</li>
<li>Your email.</li>
</span></div>
</div>
```